# ASP.NET MVC common model for different controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having a hard time understanding the way MVC behaves. In my Controller class I created a model and initialized it the main ActionMethod. After that I call another controller method and it turns out that the model is null. Why is that?

Now it seems I can only use them once for passing database info to the views. Is it necessary to always modify/query the database? I know in most cases it makes sense to do it, but I would like to keep these parts separate.

**Edit:**
Here's some code:

```
public class TestController : Controller {
   TestModel model;

   public ActionResult Index() {
      model = new TestModel();
      return View(model);
   }

   public ActionResult OtherMethod {
      // Here I would like to access/modify the previously created model, but it is null
      return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: You should show us more code. There is no restriction on number of model usages

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions based on your lack of knowledge.  I suggest you go to http://asp.net/mvc and read some tutorials

Comment: HTTP is stateless. Each request you start with a clean slate. Explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Html helpers](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp) to bind properties of your model in view

or simply use @Html.EditorForModel() helper. It will create UI and binding for entire model

Answer (score -1):

the default lifetime of controller is "per request" this means that a new instance of your TestController is created on every HttpRequest.

you could change this behavior by creating a custom controller factory but i would not recommend that, i suggest u use the TempData collection instead.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx